# Select some fields to sync via Change Data Capture

Tags: change-data-capture

I am using Change Data Capture (CDC) to sync objects but I would like to only sync some fields not all the fields, is this possible?

Let's say I would like only to sync the field called Name in the object Opportunity, is this possible or Salesforce via CDC always force me to sync all fields no matter what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe by syncing you mean you might be listening to CDC raised by an salesforce org into another or via some external application.

So the org raising the CDC event will include any changed fields, you cannot select which fields to trigger `CDC` from.

But after listening to this event in your custom application or different org, you may choose to ignore events which you are not interested in.

**BTW:**

In your use case, I believe `Platform Event` would be a better approach, so that you dont unnecessarily consume delivery events. So you can raise `Platform event` only when you detect a change in your desired fields.